# WCF Add Service Reference - Collection type keeps trying to use System.Array

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, web-services, wcf

I am having a problem adding a custom WCF service reference to my WPF application. I have been working on this service and application for nearly 6 months now and have never run into this issue until today. Whenever I try and add the WCF service via "Add Service Reference," all of my methods that return List are trying to return T[] instead. When I configure the service reference and change the collection type to "System.Collection.Generics.List", It shows in the status bar that it is updating the reference code, but the methods in the WPF application are throwing errors stating that it can't implicitly convert from List to Array. It seemed to have happened after I pushed an update to the server, but the only thing that was changed was the way one of my objects is initialized. I have tried the following so far;

- Cleaned the project
- Cleaned the solution
- Rebuild the solution
- Manually deleted the obj/bin/Service Reference folders
- Removed and re-published the wcf service
- Restarted the server

Im at a complete loss and have no idea what to do at this point. Any help is greatly appreciated!

**Update**

I created a separate console project, and it hooks into the WCF service correctly once configured to return lists. Looks to be specifically an issue with the WPF project.

**Update 2**

I noticed the following errors showing up briefly when I try to build. They disappear after a while, but I don't know if this has anything to do with the issue. They are both in the App.config file.

- The 'bindingConfiguration' attribute is invalid - The value 'BasicHttpBinding_ICustomService' is invalid according to its datatype 'serviceBindingConfigurationType' - The Enumeration constraint failed.
- The 'contract' attribute is invalid - The value 'CustomServerSvc.ICustomServer' is invalid according to its datatype 'clientContractType' - The Enumeration constraint failed.

**Update 3**

Interestingly, this only seems to happen on the client side randomly after a build.

Adding in my web.config per request.

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
      <section name="UnifyServer.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DebugUnifyCS"
          connectionString="connectionString"
          providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="UnifyCS"
          connectionString="connectionString"
          providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <client />
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="myBasicBinding" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxBufferSize="2147483647"
          maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" receiveTimeout="00:30:00" sendTimeout="00:30:00">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="128" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
            maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <!--<bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IUnifyServer" >
          <security mode="None" />
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>-->
      <services>
        <service name="UnifyServer.UnifyServer">
          <endpoint address="UnifyServer" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="myBasicBinding" contract="UnifyServer.IUnifyServer"></endpoint>
          <host>
            <baseAddresses>
              <add baseAddress="http://unifysrv2012:19081/"/>
            </baseAddresses>
          </host>
        </service>
        <service name="UnifyServer.ServiceEndpoint">
          <endpoint address="ServiceEndpoint" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="myBasicBinding" contract="UnifyServer.IServiceEndpoint"></endpoint>
          <host>
            <baseAddresses>
              <add baseAddress="http://unifysrv2012:19081/"/>
            </baseAddresses>
          </host>
        </service>
      </services>
      <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
        <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>    
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

  <applicationSettings>
    <UnifyServer.Properties.Settings>
      <setting name="UnifyServer_some_service" serializeAs="String">
        <value>https://some.url.com/some_service.asmx</value>
      </setting>
    </UnifyServer.Properties.Settings>
  </applicationSettings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: So when you add a new service reference, your existing code base gets modified?

Comment: It looks like it adds the relevant files under the Service Reference folder in Explorer, and it does correct all the missing references throughout the application. It just keeps trying to return the collections as arrays no matter what I configure it as.

Comment: Are you using the same names/namespaces? Would those cause conflicts?

Comment: Namespaces are different. The client(WPF) application doesn't contain any custom defined objects, I am only using the definitions from the server.

Comment: You say you're working on the service and the application?  Why, then, don't you just re-use the interface in the client, rather than making visual studio try to figure it out from the wsdl?  Your code will be smaller and faster, the types will be correct, and it'll even compile quicker.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt any service reference is updated since you are getting error while updating service reference.

Try start by these steps, each step is independent to other & might be cause of issue:

- Make sure `[ServiceContract]` is declared for the interface of your services, because this produces the exact error.
- If you have re-factored code or changed any file/namespace. make sure its applied everywhere.
- Use fully qualified service name in `web.config` with `Namespace`;
- Make sure `System.ServiceModel` & `System.Runtime.Serialization` reference is not missing.
- Delete `.SUO` (solution Users Option file) file after closing VS. This will reset the cache for `XMLEditor` component in VS.

---

**Update**

For error `The 'bindingConfiguration' attribute is invalid - The value 'BasicHttpBinding_ICustomService' is invalid according to its datatype 'serviceBindingConfigurationType' - The Enumeration constraint failed.`

Make sure all service interface/contract have `[ServiceContract]` attribute, methods have `[Operation Contract]`.

Also make sure all DataContract Attributes have `[DataMember]` Or **enum** have `[EnumMember]` attribute.

---

**Update 2**

One case I have faced was some attribute wasn't able to serialize. e.g. I was returning `DataSet` that can't be serialized to binary by default by wcf, that cause the error.

In worst case, you have to separate Data contracts & reuse them & have to generate proxy manually using SVCUtil. I know it sounds crazy. But sometimes when all things doesn't work it seems to be working.

Let me know it works or not.

Comment: I have done everything listed above. Never heard of deleting the SUO file but I tried it anyways. Still no luck.

Comment: Please add web.config & service contract in questionitself, it can help someone to spot something that might be root of issue.

Comment: My development machine is currently undergoing maintenance. I will upload it as soon as it is back online. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Web.config has been added.

Comment: Thanks for the update, I found a few methods that weren't decorated with DataContract, but beyond that everything else looks clean. I went through each and every method and property to ensure it all looks good. The thing that is most confusing is it seems to be specific to this project. If I browse the service in the Object Browser of this project, it does show that it is trying to return T[], but the references.svcmap file is trying to serialize as List<T>.

Answer (score 0):

This happens often so when you are adding the reference to the WCF service check this:

1. In the "**Add service reference**" screen press the "Advanced..." button (at the bottom).
2. In the middle part of the "**Service reference settings**" screen that you just opened you'll see 2 combos where you specify the **collection type**, select the right ones and click ok.

[image]